Are Christoffel symbols in Schwarzschild metric symmetric?
Schwarzschild metric is following
$$ ds^2 = (1-\frac{r_s}{r})c^2dt^2 -\frac{dr^2}{1-\frac{r_s}{r}} - r^2d\theta^2 - r^2\sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2
$$
Metric tensor has only diagonal terms non zero from this metric. Using formula for calculate Christoffel symbols in term of metric tensor
$$
\Gamma^a_{bc} = \frac{g^{am}}{2}(\partial_bg_{cm} + \partial_cg_{bm} - \partial_mg_{bc})
$$
the Christoffel symbols are symmetric under change of lower indexes because equation
$$
\Gamma^a_{cb} = \frac{g^{am}}{2}(\partial_cg_{bm} + \partial_bg_{cm} - \partial_mg_{cb})
$$
is the same with first equation. But if i use this equation
$ \Gamma^a_{cb} = \frac{\partial e_c}{\partial x^b}e^a $
to calculate Christoffel symbols i will get slightly different results. Time and radial basis vectors in Schwarzschild metric are
$ e'_t = \sqrt{1-\frac{r_s}{r}}e_t;\, e'_r = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{r_s}{r}}}e_r $
where $ e_t \,,e_r $ are time and radial basis vectors in polar coordinates respectively.
$$
\Gamma^a_{rt} = \Gamma^a_{10} = \frac{\partial e'_r}{\partial x^t}{e^a}' = 0;\, a=t,r
$$
because radial basis vector don't change with respect to time coordinate.
$$
\Gamma^a_{tr} = \Gamma^a_{01} = \frac{\partial e'_t}{\partial x^r}{e^a}' = \partial_r(\sqrt{1-\frac{r_s}{r}}e_t){e^a}' = \frac{r_s}{2r^2\sqrt{1-\frac{r_s}{r}}}e_t{e^a}'
$$
$$
\Gamma^t_{tr} = \frac{r_s}{2r(r-r_s)},\, \Gamma^r_{tr} = 0
$$
$$
\Gamma^t_{rt} = 0,\,\Gamma^r_{rt} = 0
$$
Let's calculate $\Gamma^r_{tt}$ using equation in term of metric tensor.
$$
 \Gamma^r_{tt} = \frac{g^{rm}}{2}(\partial_tg_{tm} + \partial_tg_{tm} - \partial_mg_{tt})= \frac{r_s(r-r_s)}{r^3}
$$
Using equation with one derivative of basis vector to calculate Christoffel symbol with the same indexes i got
$$
  \Gamma^r_{tt} = \frac{\partial e'_t}{\partial x^t}{e^r}' = \partial_t(\sqrt{1-\frac{r_s}{r}}e_t){e^r}'=0
$$
because $e'_t$ doesn't depend of time coordinate. Both equations in term of metric tensor and basis vectors seems to be not the same. What is the difference between Christoffel symbols calculated from this two equations? Do the Christoffel symbols can be nonsymmetric in Schwarzschild metric and other Einstein field quations solutions?

what is $1/e_a$? how do you divide by a vector?

It is time or radial basis vector because a can be t or r index. Primed basis vectors are Schwarzschild basis, nonprimed basis are basis in polar coordinates. I divided by vector because basis vectors in numerator and denominator are same.

you still can't divide by a vector.

There was mistake. The e_t polar basis was missing.

I think the OP means $\partial_\beta\mathbf{e}\alpha = \Gamma^\gamma{\alpha\beta}\mathbf{e}\gamma$. As @paulina points out, you can't divide both sides by the vector $\mathbf{e}\gamma$. Dividing by vectors is not generally defined, plus $\mathbf{e}_\gamma$ is contracted with the Christoffel symbol so there's an implied summation.

anyway, the christoffel symbols are always symmetric in their lower indices for a connection which is torsion-free. this statement can be formulated without reference to a specific coordinate system, so no, the christoffel symbols for the Schwarzschild metric are always symmetric in their lower indices.

If I take derivative of time basis vector with respect time coordinate I got zero in Schwarzschild metric. This means that Christoffel symbols also must be zero. But equation in term of metric tensor gives non zero Christoffel symbol. From this I concluded that Christoffel symbols from this two equations are not the same. I have taken concrete metric to easier understand what going on.

@Aiden Your equation is incorrect. The correct definition is $\nabla_\beta \mathbf{e}\alpha = \Gamma^\gamma{\alpha\beta} \mathbf{e}_\gamma$. $\partial$ does not make sense when applied to a vector.

@VincentThacker Thanks for the catch! It should be a covariant derivative here. However, I've seen many GR texts which define $\partial$ so that it can act on vectors (at least in Euclidean space). See e.g. Schutz's book on GR or Hobson, Efstathiou, and Lasenby's GR text, or the wiki page on Christoffel symbols. These references explicitly write $\partial_\beta\mathbf{e}\alpha=\Gamma^\gamma{\alpha\beta}\mathbf{e}_\gamma$.
